# Why does Windows 10 Hotspot feature give me "No internet connection"?

Tags: windows-10, internet-connection, wireless-hotspot

For VR I wanted to get a better link directly to my PC. So I bought a WiFi device and turned on the Hotspot feature.

My headset connected to the PC just fine, and streaming from PC to headset works. However, the headset complains it has no internet connection.

In Windows, everything seems fine.

Web pages such as these, give plenty of suggestions, none of them work: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/hotspot-connecting-but-saying-no-internet-access/5c976ff4-233e-492d-8f5f-e84478e08c7d

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I had a local DNS server interfering with the hotspot feature. All I needed to do was turn it off and configure my regular network connection accordingly.

The only thing not working was the IP-address for the DNS server, provided by Windows to the wireless headset. Windows's Hotspot feature uses DHCP to configure an IP-address, DNS, and default gateway to the wireless device. But the DNS service couldn't bind to my local machine because I already had a DNS server running locally.